# How to embed Jupyter live on a webpage?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

How would I use an iframe to embed Jupyter, live (not converted to HTML), on a webpage? We are trying to embed live Jupyter notebooks from JupyterHub in programming tutorials. I believe that I will have to enable something to do with CORS? Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You have put your webpage's url in Content-Security-Policy in jupyterhub_config.py (jupyterhub's config file) and jupyter_notebook_config.py (notebook's config file).

In jupyterhub_config.py

```
c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' http://<your-webpage-url>"
    }
}
```

In jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' http://<your-webpage-url>:4200"
    }
}
```